How to add dynamic url to canonical tag in Next.js 14.2.4
I am trying to add dynamic url to my Next.js dynamic routes.
I am using server rendered page to generate metadata:
export const metadata: Metadata = {
   title: `InterviewQA |  ItsIndianGuy`,
   description:
      "Explore interview questions in various programming languages such as JavaScript, Python, C++ and more. Enhance your preparation with comprehensive language-specific content.",
   alternates: {
      canonical: "https://itsindianguy.in/interview-qa",
   },
};

The dynamic page i want to add seo for is in pic

Now the problem is, I have added it to static pages, but when it comes to dynamic pages, how do I add it?
Because I can't use hooks to get the pathname in Server rendered pages.
What can I try next?

You can add this at the top your your dynamic page:
import type { Metadata, ResolvingMetadata } from 'next'

type Props = {
   params: { slug: string }
   searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
 }

 export async function generateMetadata(
  { params, searchParams }: Props,
    parent: ResolvingMetadata
   ): Promise<Metadata> {
  // read route params
   const slug = params.slug

 // fetch data or use local json data
 const product = await fetch(`https://.../${slug}`).then((res) => res.json())


return {
   title: product.title,
 }
}


Thank you very much, I was struggling to find the exact solution. I read documentation but it was not clear for me completely.
